# How to access R data.frame column descriptions after read.spss

Tags: r, dataframe

I have imported an SPSS .sav file using the library foreign read.spss function.

```
dataset = read.spss("data.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE)
```

I want to access the column descriptions but can't work out how to access them programmatically. I can see these in the data viewer in RStudio, in the header just below the bold column names.

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgIO5.png

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may be better off importing the data using the `read_sav` function from the [haven](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/index.html) package (another great package from Hadley Wickham).

#### Read a 'sav' file:

```
dd <- read_sav("SomeFile.sav")

head(dd)[,1:10]

methods(as_factor)
table(dd$District)
class(dd$District)
class(dd$Date)
lapply(dd, class)   # some variables have labels and others don't
lapply(dd, class) %>% head
```

#### The 'labelled' variables have attributes to show their variable label ('label') and their value labels ('labels')

```
dd$Region
attributes(dd$Region)
```

#### You can read a variable label:

```
attr(dd$Region, 'label')
```

#### You can change a variable label:

```
attr(dd$Region, 'label') <- 'a new label for Region'
attr(dd$Region, 'label')
```

#### same for value labels

```
attr(dd$Region, 'labels')
```

#### to change the names, you need to change the 'names' of the attribute

```
names(attr(dd$Region, 'labels')) <- c("NE","Nyanza","West")
attr(dd$Region, 'labels')
```

Comment: `attributes(dd$Region)` gets the label for only 1 column. How do we do that complete dataframe and same in a separate row or column into a separate row or dataframe ?

Answer (score 2):

The list of variable labels can be accessed with `attributes(dataset)$variable.labels`.